# Удаление элемента в отсортированной модели QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: c++, qt

Есть такая модель:

```
 class CustomModel : public QAbstractItemModel
 {
   public:
     CustomModel(QObject *parent) : QAbstractItemModel(parent)
     {
       _data.push_back("A");
       _data.push_back("D");
       _data.push_back("B1");
       _data.push_back("B");
     }
   ~CustomModel() {}

void deleteNode(const QModelIndex& index)
{
    int begin = index.row();
    beginRemoveRows(index.parent(), begin, begin);
    _data.erase(_data.begin() + begin);
    endRemoveRows();
}

virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override
{
    if (!parent.isValid())
        return 1;

    if ((int)parent.internalPointer() == _root )
        return _data.size();

    return 0;
}
virtual int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override
{
    return 1;
}
virtual QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const override
{
    if (!hasIndex(row, column, parent))
        return QModelIndex();
    if (!parent.isValid())
        return createIndex(row, 0, _root);

    return createIndex(row, 0, row);
    
}
virtual QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &index) const override
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QModelIndex();
    if ((int)index.internalPointer() == _root)
        return QModelIndex();
    int parentId = 9;
    return createIndex(index.row(), 0, _root);
}
virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    try
    {
        switch (role)
        {
        case Qt::DisplayRole:
        {
            if ((int)index.internalPointer() == _root)
                return QString("Root");
            return QString::fromStdString(_data[index.row()]);
        }
        default:
            return QVariant();
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return QVariant();
    }
}


 private:
  int _root = 200;
  std::vector<std::string> _data;
 };
```

Я хочу отобразить эту модель в отсортированном виде. Вставляю эту модель в `QSortFilterProxyModel` следующим образом:

```
proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel;

sourceView = new QTreeView;
sourceView->setRootIsDecorated(false);
sourceView->setAlternatingRowColors(true);

proxyView = new QTreeView;
proxyView->setRootIsDecorated(false);
proxyView->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
proxyView->setModel(proxyModel);
proxyView->setSortingEnabled(true);

proxyView->sortByColumn(0, Qt::AscendingOrder);

////

proxyModel->setSourceModel(model);
proxyModel->setDynamicSortFilter(true);
sourceView->setModel(model);
```

При нажатии на кнопку удаления выделенной строки отрабатывает этот код:

```
 void Window::delete()
 {
     QModelIndex index = proxyView->currentIndex();
     _model->deleteNode(proxyModel->mapToSource(index));
 }
```

В результате я получаю следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В отсортированной модели (нижнее окно) на месте удаляемого элемента (между А и В1) находится пустая строка, в неотсортированном представлении все отображается корректно.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Я не знаю как правильно, но у меня сработало добавление `proxyModel->invalidate()` в конец метода удаления. Вероятно что не подключены(либо не вызываются) нужные сигналы.

Comment: Добрый день @Maxim, это работает, но вызывает другую проблему - при удалении строки появляется горизонтальный scrollbar, который обеспечивает прокрутку в пустую часть qtreeview, как будто там существует элемент.

Comment: @Telna, Я думаю, что стоит уведомить представление об изменении данных ;)
Воспользуйтесь этим кодом: 
QModelIndex topLeft = createIndex(0, 0);
emit dataChanged(topLeft, topLeft);